# How to find the probability from a moment-generating function?

Tags: probability, statistics

The following MGF is given:

$M_{w}(t) = e^{-3+3e^t}*(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}e^t)^4$

I must calculate P(W<2).

I understand that this is comprised of two independent MGFs, $M_x(t)$ and $M_y(t)$, that are from the Poisson distribution and the Binomial distribution, respectively.  I am stuck at this point -- to find P(W<2), do I simply solve by doing the following, or do I need to do something more that relates to the distributions themselves?

$P_x(0)$*$P_y(0)$ + $P_x(1)*P_y(0) + P_x(0)*P_y(1)$?

Comment: Do you recognize the form of $W$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes -- W = X + Y and through independence, we can say $M_x(t)*M_y(t)$. I suppose what I am trying to understand is how to get the probability from the moment-generating function.

Comment: Your approach is perfectly adequate, except the notations could be better.